# 500 OOPS: SSL: cannot load RSA private key

Tags: ubuntu, ftp, sftp, rsa

I am trying to debug a FTP server. I am currently getting

```
$ sudo /usr/sbin/vsftpd
500 OOPS: SSL: cannot load RSA private key
```

FTP connections are being refused. This is that status of from systemctl:

```
$ sudo systemctl status vsftpd.service
● vsftpd.service - vsftpd FTP server
   Loaded: loaded (/lib/systemd/system/vsftpd.service; enabled; vendor preset: enabled)
   Active: failed (Result: exit-code) since Wed 2019-05-15 20:40:34 UTC; 7min ago
  Process: 3220 ExecStart=/usr/sbin/vsftpd /etc/vsftpd.conf (code=exited, status=2)
  Process: 3217 ExecStartPre=/bin/mkdir -p /var/run/vsftpd/empty (code=exited, status=0/SUCCESS)
 Main PID: 3220 (code=exited, status=2)

May 15 20:40:34 ip-10-0-0-27 systemd[1]: Stopped vsftpd FTP server.
May 15 20:40:34 ip-10-0-0-27 systemd[1]: Starting vsftpd FTP server...
May 15 20:40:34 ip-10-0-0-27 systemd[1]: Started vsftpd FTP server.
May 15 20:40:34 ip-10-0-0-27 systemd[1]: vsftpd.service: Main process exited, code=exited, status=2/INVALIDARGUMENT
May 15 20:40:34 ip-10-0-0-27 systemd[1]: vsftpd.service: Unit entered failed state.
May 15 20:40:34 ip-10-0-0-27 systemd[1]: vsftpd.service: Failed with result 'exit-code'.
```

Somethings is likely wring with the key file, but I don't know why. It looks normal to me:

```
$ sudo ls -l /etc/ssl/private/wildcard.key
-r-------- 1 root root 1679 May 15 20:38 /etc/ssl/private/wildcard.key
```

And contains

```
-----BEGIN RSA PRIVATE KEY-----
...
-----END RSA PRIVATE KEY-----
```

Contents of  `/etc/vsftpd.conf`:

```
use_localtime=YES
hide_ids=YES

# Logging
dual_log_enable=YES
xferlog_enable=YES
log_ftp_protocol=YES
debug_ssl=YES

#listen_ipv6=YES
listen=YES

# Local users
anonymous_enable=NO
write_enable=YES
local_enable=YES
chroot_local_user=YES
allow_writeable_chroot=YES
secure_chroot_dir=/run/vsftpd/empty
user_sub_token=$USER
local_root=/home/$USER/incoming

# TLS/SSL

ssl_enable=YES
force_local_data_ssl=YES
force_local_logins_ssl=YES
rsa_cert_file=/etc/ssl/private/wildcard.crt
rsa_private_key_file=/etc/ssl/private/wildcard.key
ssl_sslv2=NO
ssl_sslv3=YES
ssl_tlsv1=YES

ssl_ciphers=ECDHE-RSA-AES256-GCM-SHA384:AES256-SHA
strict_ssl_read_eof=NO
ssl_request_cert=NO
require_ssl_reuse=NO

# Passive mode
pasv_enable=YES
pasv_address=[REDACTED]
pasv_min_port=50000
pasv_max_port=50099
```

Output of strace:

```
$strace /usr/sbin/vsftpd /etc/vsftpd.conf
execve("/usr/sbin/vsftpd", ["/usr/sbin/vsftpd", "/etc/vsftpd.conf"], [/* 22 vars */]) = 0
brk(0)                                  = 0x7f3c864aa000
access("/etc/ld.so.nohwcap", F_OK)      = -1 ENOENT (No such file or directory)
access("/etc/ld.so.preload", R_OK)      = -1 ENOENT (No such file or directory)
open("/etc/ld.so.cache", O_RDONLY|O_CLOEXEC) = 3
fstat(3, {st_mode=S_IFREG|0644, st_size=24984, ...}) = 0
mmap(NULL, 24984, PROT_READ, MAP_PRIVATE, 3, 0) = 0x7f3c85d15000
close(3)                                = 0
access("/etc/ld.so.nohwcap", F_OK)      = -1 ENOENT (No such file or directory)
open("/lib/x86_64-linux-gnu/libwrap.so.0", O_RDONLY|O_CLOEXEC) = 3
read(3, "\177ELF\2\1\1\0\0\0\0\0\0\0\0\0\3\0>\0\1\0\0\0p-\0\0\0\0\0\0"..., 832) = 832
fstat(3, {st_mode=S_IFREG|0644, st_size=36632, ...}) = 0
mmap(NULL, 4096, PROT_READ|PROT_WRITE, MAP_PRIVATE|MAP_ANONYMOUS, -1, 0) = 0x7f3c85d14000
mmap(NULL, 2134176, PROT_READ|PROT_EXEC, MAP_PRIVATE|MAP_DENYWRITE, 3, 0) = 0x7f3c856c7000
mprotect(0x7f3c856cf000, 2093056, PROT_NONE) = 0
mmap(0x7f3c858ce000, 8192, PROT_READ|PROT_WRITE, MAP_PRIVATE|MAP_FIXED|MAP_DENYWRITE, 3, 0x7000) = 0x7f3c858ce000
mmap(0x7f3c858d0000, 160, PROT_READ|PROT_WRITE, MAP_PRIVATE|MAP_FIXED|MAP_ANONYMOUS, -1, 0) = 0x7f3c858d0000
close(3)                                = 0
access("/etc/ld.so.nohwcap", F_OK)      = -1 ENOENT (No such file or directory)
open("/lib/x86_64-linux-gnu/libpam.so.0", O_RDONLY|O_CLOEXEC) = 3
read(3, "\177ELF\2\1\1\0\0\0\0\0\0\0\0\0\3\0>\0\1\0\0\0\300$\0\0\0\0\0\0"..., 832) = 832
fstat(3, {st_mode=S_IFREG|0644, st_size=55856, ...}) = 0
mmap(NULL, 2150904, PROT_READ|PROT_EXEC, MAP_PRIVATE|MAP_DENYWRITE, 3, 0) = 0x7f3c854b9000
mprotect(0x7f3c854c6000, 2093056, PROT_NONE) = 0
mmap(0x7f3c856c5000, 8192, PROT_READ|PROT_WRITE, MAP_PRIVATE|MAP_FIXED|MAP_DENYWRITE, 3, 0xc000) = 0x7f3c856c5000
close(3)                                = 0
access("/etc/ld.so.nohwcap", F_OK)      = -1 ENOENT (No such file or directory)
open("/lib/x86_64-linux-gnu/libssl.so.1.0.0", O_RDONLY|O_CLOEXEC) = 3
read(3, "\177ELF\2\1\1\0\0\0\0\0\0\0\0\0\3\0>\0\1\0\0\0\240.\1\0\0\0\0\0"..., 832) = 832
fstat(3, {st_mode=S_IFREG|0644, st_size=387272, ...}) = 0
mmap(NULL, 2482576, PROT_READ|PROT_EXEC, MAP_PRIVATE|MAP_DENYWRITE, 3, 0) = 0x7f3c8525a000
mprotect(0x7f3c852af000, 2097152, PROT_NONE) = 0
mmap(0x7f3c854af000, 40960, PROT_READ|PROT_WRITE, MAP_PRIVATE|MAP_FIXED|MAP_DENYWRITE, 3, 0x55000) = 0x7f3c854af000
close(3)                                = 0
access("/etc/ld.so.nohwcap", F_OK)      = -1 ENOENT (No such file or directory)
open("/lib/x86_64-linux-gnu/libcrypto.so.1.0.0", O_RDONLY|O_CLOEXEC) = 3
read(3, "\177ELF\2\1\1\0\0\0\0\0\0\0\0\0\3\0>\0\1\0\0\0\200\356\5\0\0\0\0\0"..., 832) = 832
fstat(3, {st_mode=S_IFREG|0644, st_size=1938752, ...}) = 0
mmap(NULL, 4096, PROT_READ|PROT_WRITE, MAP_PRIVATE|MAP_ANONYMOUS, -1, 0) = 0x7f3c85d13000
mmap(NULL, 4049080, PROT_READ|PROT_EXEC, MAP_PRIVATE|MAP_DENYWRITE, 3, 0) = 0x7f3c84e7d000
mprotect(0x7f3c85030000, 2097152, PROT_NONE) = 0
mmap(0x7f3c85230000, 155648, PROT_READ|PROT_WRITE, MAP_PRIVATE|MAP_FIXED|MAP_DENYWRITE, 3, 0x1b3000) = 0x7f3c85230000
mmap(0x7f3c85256000, 14520, PROT_READ|PROT_WRITE, MAP_PRIVATE|MAP_FIXED|MAP_ANONYMOUS, -1, 0) = 0x7f3c85256000
close(3)                                = 0
access("/etc/ld.so.nohwcap", F_OK)      = -1 ENOENT (No such file or directory)
open("/lib/x86_64-linux-gnu/libcap.so.2", O_RDONLY|O_CLOEXEC) = 3
read(3, "\177ELF\2\1\1\0\0\0\0\0\0\0\0\0\3\0>\0\1\0\0\0 \26\0\0\0\0\0\0"..., 832) = 832
fstat(3, {st_mode=S_IFREG|0644, st_size=18952, ...}) = 0
mmap(NULL, 2114160, PROT_READ|PROT_EXEC, MAP_PRIVATE|MAP_DENYWRITE, 3, 0) = 0x7f3c84c78000
mprotect(0x7f3c84c7c000, 2093056, PROT_NONE) = 0
mmap(0x7f3c84e7b000, 8192, PROT_READ|PROT_WRITE, MAP_PRIVATE|MAP_FIXED|MAP_DENYWRITE, 3, 0x3000) = 0x7f3c84e7b000
close(3)                                = 0
access("/etc/ld.so.nohwcap", F_OK)      = -1 ENOENT (No such file or directory)
open("/lib/x86_64-linux-gnu/libc.so.6", O_RDONLY|O_CLOEXEC) = 3
read(3, "\177ELF\2\1\1\0\0\0\0\0\0\0\0\0\3\0>\0\1\0\0\0P \2\0\0\0\0\0"..., 832) = 832
fstat(3, {st_mode=S_IFREG|0755, st_size=1857312, ...}) = 0
mmap(NULL, 3965632, PROT_READ|PROT_EXEC, MAP_PRIVATE|MAP_DENYWRITE, 3, 0) = 0x7f3c848af000
mprotect(0x7f3c84a6d000, 2097152, PROT_NONE) = 0
mmap(0x7f3c84c6d000, 24576, PROT_READ|PROT_WRITE, MAP_PRIVATE|MAP_FIXED|MAP_DENYWRITE, 3, 0x1be000) = 0x7f3c84c6d000
mmap(0x7f3c84c73000, 17088, PROT_READ|PROT_WRITE, MAP_PRIVATE|MAP_FIXED|MAP_ANONYMOUS, -1, 0) = 0x7f3c84c73000
close(3)                                = 0
access("/etc/ld.so.nohwcap", F_OK)      = -1 ENOENT (No such file or directory)
open("/lib/x86_64-linux-gnu/libnsl.so.1", O_RDONLY|O_CLOEXEC) = 3
read(3, "\177ELF\2\1\1\0\0\0\0\0\0\0\0\0\3\0>\0\1\0\0\0`A\0\0\0\0\0\0"..., 832) = 832
fstat(3, {st_mode=S_IFREG|0644, st_size=97296, ...}) = 0
mmap(NULL, 4096, PROT_READ|PROT_WRITE, MAP_PRIVATE|MAP_ANONYMOUS, -1, 0) = 0x7f3c85d12000
mmap(NULL, 2202328, PROT_READ|PROT_EXEC, MAP_PRIVATE|MAP_DENYWRITE, 3, 0) = 0x7f3c84695000
mprotect(0x7f3c846ac000, 2093056, PROT_NONE) = 0
mmap(0x7f3c848ab000, 8192, PROT_READ|PROT_WRITE, MAP_PRIVATE|MAP_FIXED|MAP_DENYWRITE, 3, 0x16000) = 0x7f3c848ab000
mmap(0x7f3c848ad000, 6872, PROT_READ|PROT_WRITE, MAP_PRIVATE|MAP_FIXED|MAP_ANONYMOUS, -1, 0) = 0x7f3c848ad000
close(3)                                = 0
access("/etc/ld.so.nohwcap", F_OK)      = -1 ENOENT (No such file or directory)
open("/lib/x86_64-linux-gnu/libaudit.so.1", O_RDONLY|O_CLOEXEC) = 3
read(3, "\177ELF\2\1\1\0\0\0\0\0\0\0\0\0\3\0>\0\1\0\0\0\240(\0\0\0\0\0\0"..., 832) = 832
fstat(3, {st_mode=S_IFREG|0644, st_size=104936, ...}) = 0
mmap(NULL, 2241056, PROT_READ|PROT_EXEC, MAP_PRIVATE|MAP_DENYWRITE, 3, 0) = 0x7f3c84471000
mprotect(0x7f3c8448a000, 2093056, PROT_NONE) = 0
mmap(0x7f3c84689000, 8192, PROT_READ|PROT_WRITE, MAP_PRIVATE|MAP_FIXED|MAP_DENYWRITE, 3, 0x18000) = 0x7f3c84689000
mmap(0x7f3c8468b000, 37408, PROT_READ|PROT_WRITE, MAP_PRIVATE|MAP_FIXED|MAP_ANONYMOUS, -1, 0) = 0x7f3c8468b000
close(3)                                = 0
access("/etc/ld.so.nohwcap", F_OK)      = -1 ENOENT (No such file or directory)
open("/lib/x86_64-linux-gnu/libdl.so.2", O_RDONLY|O_CLOEXEC) = 3
read(3, "\177ELF\2\1\1\0\0\0\0\0\0\0\0\0\3\0>\0\1\0\0\0\320\16\0\0\0\0\0\0"..., 832) = 832
fstat(3, {st_mode=S_IFREG|0644, st_size=14664, ...}) = 0
mmap(NULL, 2109744, PROT_READ|PROT_EXEC, MAP_PRIVATE|MAP_DENYWRITE, 3, 0) = 0x7f3c8426d000
mprotect(0x7f3c84270000, 2093056, PROT_NONE) = 0
mmap(0x7f3c8446f000, 8192, PROT_READ|PROT_WRITE, MAP_PRIVATE|MAP_FIXED|MAP_DENYWRITE, 3, 0x2000) = 0x7f3c8446f000
close(3)                                = 0
mmap(NULL, 4096, PROT_READ|PROT_WRITE, MAP_PRIVATE|MAP_ANONYMOUS, -1, 0) = 0x7f3c85d11000
mmap(NULL, 4096, PROT_READ|PROT_WRITE, MAP_PRIVATE|MAP_ANONYMOUS, -1, 0) = 0x7f3c85d10000
mmap(NULL, 8192, PROT_READ|PROT_WRITE, MAP_PRIVATE|MAP_ANONYMOUS, -1, 0) = 0x7f3c85d0e000
arch_prctl(ARCH_SET_FS, 0x7f3c85d0e740) = 0
mprotect(0x7f3c84c6d000, 16384, PROT_READ) = 0
mprotect(0x7f3c8446f000, 4096, PROT_READ) = 0
mprotect(0x7f3c84689000, 4096, PROT_READ) = 0
mprotect(0x7f3c848ab000, 4096, PROT_READ) = 0
mprotect(0x7f3c84e7b000, 4096, PROT_READ) = 0
mprotect(0x7f3c85230000, 110592, PROT_READ) = 0
mprotect(0x7f3c854af000, 12288, PROT_READ) = 0
mprotect(0x7f3c856c5000, 4096, PROT_READ) = 0
mprotect(0x7f3c858ce000, 4096, PROT_READ) = 0
mprotect(0x7f3c85d1c000, 4096, PROT_READ) = 0
mprotect(0x7f3c85af3000, 4096, PROT_READ) = 0
munmap(0x7f3c85d15000, 24984)           = 0
brk(0)                                  = 0x7f3c864aa000
brk(0x7f3c864cb000)                     = 0x7f3c864cb000
open("/etc/vsftpd.conf", O_RDONLY|O_NONBLOCK) = 3
fstat(3, {st_mode=S_IFREG|0644, st_size=1177, ...}) = 0
mmap(NULL, 12288, PROT_READ|PROT_WRITE, MAP_PRIVATE|MAP_ANONYMOUS, -1, 0) = 0x7f3c85d19000
mprotect(0x7f3c85d1b000, 4096, PROT_NONE) = 0
mprotect(0x7f3c85d19000, 4096, PROT_NONE) = 0
read(3, "# General. See http://vsftpd.bea"..., 1177) = 1177
mprotect(0x7f3c85d19000, 4096, PROT_READ) = 0
munmap(0x7f3c85d19000, 12288)           = 0
close(3)                                = 0
stat("/etc/vsftpd.conf", {st_mode=S_IFREG|0644, st_size=1177, ...}) = 0
getuid()                                = 0
getuid()                                = 0
getpid()                                = 7409
open("/dev/urandom", O_RDONLY|O_NOCTTY|O_NONBLOCK) = 3
fstat(3, {st_mode=S_IFCHR|0666, st_rdev=makedev(1, 9), ...}) = 0
poll([{fd=3, events=POLLIN}], 1, 10)    = 1 ([{fd=3, revents=POLLIN}])
read(3, "\204\30>\303\fE\234\240VU\233\10\313\361\354^\217@\231\367`\274\260\241\357\234u\211aR^T", 32) = 32
close(3)                                = 0
getuid()                                = 0
open("/etc/ssl/private/wildcard.crt", O_RDONLY) = 3
fstat(3, {st_mode=S_IFREG|0400, st_size=8242, ...}) = 0
mmap(NULL, 4096, PROT_READ|PROT_WRITE, MAP_PRIVATE|MAP_ANONYMOUS, -1, 0) = 0x7f3c85d1b000
read(3, "-----BEGIN CERTIFICATE-----\nXXXX"..., 4096) = 4096
read(3, "XXX..."..., 4096) = 4096
read(3, "XXX...=\n-----EN"..., 4096) = 50
read(3, "", 4096)                       = 0
read(3, "", 4096)                       = 0
close(3)                                = 0
munmap(0x7f3c85d1b000, 4096)            = 0
open("/etc/ssl/private/wildcard.key", O_RDONLY) = 3
fstat(3, {st_mode=S_IFREG|0400, st_size=1704, ...}) = 0
mmap(NULL, 4096, PROT_READ|PROT_WRITE, MAP_PRIVATE|MAP_ANONYMOUS, -1, 0) = 0x7f3c85d1b000
read(3, "-----BEGIN PRIVATE KEY-----\nXXXX"..., 4096) = 1704
close(3)                                = 0
munmap(0x7f3c85d1b000, 4096)            = 0
fcntl(0, F_GETFL)                       = 0x8002 (flags O_RDWR|O_LARGEFILE)
fcntl(0, F_SETFL, O_RDWR|O_NONBLOCK|O_LARGEFILE) = 0
write(0, "500 OOPS: ", 10500 OOPS: )              = 10
write(0, "SSL: cannot load RSA private key", 32SSL: cannot load RSA private key) = 32
write(0, "\r\n", 2
)                     = 2
exit_group(2)                           = ?
+++ exited with 2 +++
```

Comment: Do you have vsftpd specific logs ? The service may be running on another user and don't have the right to read the file

Comment: Please provide `/etc/vsftpd.conf` in your question

Comment: @SergeyNudnov Updated the post!

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I have made some checks.

Your private key is in a wrong format.

`vsftpd` expects it to be a PEM encoded PKCS#8 format private key.

You have it as PEM encoded PKCS#1 format private key. To convert it into the correct format, use the following commands:

```
cd /etc/ssl/private/
openssl pkcs8 -topk8 -nocrypt -in wildcard.key -out wildcard_new.key
mv -f wildcard_new.key wildcard.key
```

Now your key should be like following:

```
-----BEGIN PRIVATE KEY-----
...
-----END PRIVATE KEY-----
```

### Check your key and certificate match

Run the following commands to check that your private key and certificate match:

```
cd /etc/ssl/private/
openssl pkey -in wildcard.key -pubout -outform pem | sha256sum
openssl x509 -in wildcard.crt -pubkey -noout -outform pem | sha256sum
```

The commands should output the same hash values

Comment: Thanks for you comment, but unfortunately it didn't help in this case. Same problem still!

Comment: @HaraldNordgren Could you please run `sudo strace /usr/sbin/vsftpd` and add its output in your question

Comment: Updated the question with the `strace` info!

Comment: @HaraldNordgren I have added into my answer commands to check that the key and certificate match. Also your certificate file is quite large. Is that a bundle with intermediate certificates? If so, your server certificate should be the first, and intermediate certificates should follow.

Comment: @HaraldNordgren If you `wildcard.crt`contains the private key too, it should be the first, and in that case you don't need to specify `rsa_private_key_file` in `vsftpd.conf`, or it should point to `/etc/ssl/private/wildcard.crt` too

Comment: Thank you for the update! Seems indeed that the key and certificate do not match! I will investigate why.

Comment: Thank you so much for your help Sergey. Turns out the certificates were in the wrong order. Like you noticed, it was a cert bundle, and instead of Server + Intermediate + Root we had them in the reverse order!